# LinkedIn Api v2 - Get company posts

Tags: linkedin-api

I'de like to get the last posts from my LinkedIn company page for add on my website.
I'm already created the app and generated the Access Token.
I didn't understand which endpoint I need to use, I tried this:
`https://api.linkedin.com/v2/shares?q=owners&owners=urn:li:organization:MY_COMPANY_ID` but I received the follow error:

```
  "serviceErrorCode": 100,
  "message": "Not enough permissions to access: GET-owners /shares",
  "status": 403
```

Can somebody help me?

Thanks

Comment: Could you post the piece of code related to your problem?

Comment: @abdullahalali I don't have a piece of code, I'm using Postman to send GET Request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did You request Marketing Developer Platform in Linkedin? To get information about Your company You have to own this product. Login here:

`https://www.linkedin.com/developers/`

Create app and request Marketing Developer Platform in Products section

Comment: Hi Tofikooo, Yes I had already request the marketing developer platform. How long should I wait?

Comment: I was waitng 1 week and then i have decided to write to them(support). After write to support they have accepted my request in the same day