# How to get the posts from a company page using the Linkedin API ? (Marketing declined)

Tags: php, api, linkedin-api

I would like to get the posts from a company page using the Linkedin API to display them on a website.

I try to use the PHP library [zoonman/linkedin-api-php-client](https://github.com/zoonman/linkedin-api-php-client). I created the LinkedIn application and I have a valid token. The problem is about the request.

What request should I make to get company posts?

The request for the product "Marketing Developer Platform" has been declined, is it really required as I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59045191/13969518)?

Comment: Hi! 

You're asking two questions here. For the first one, try looking at the linked in API docs, as stated in the library: 

Before you will get started, play visit to LinkedIn API Documentation. This will save you a lot of time and prevent some silly questions. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/

And for your second question, have you read this? https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/answer/112188/marketing-developer-platform-application-review